# Eclipse and Pydev plugin

Tags: eclipse, pydev

After installing and configuring PyDev plugin on Eclipse it works fine. 
BUT when I close Eclipse IDE and open it again and want to run python program I cannot because there is no Python Run.

What should I do, is there anyone who has encountered such type of error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I do not know why but the eclipse always changes the default workspace and this is creating a problem.
When I set my workspace back to a needed location the error gone and I was able to compile and run the python program.